# Suma números complejos

Tags: haskell

Soy nuevo en el lenguaje y no tengo ni idea de donde empezar con las sumas de números complejos.

Estoy usando el siguiente compilador: [Compilador online Haskell](https://repl.it/languages/haskell)
pero me sale un error:

```
"<interactive>:3:1: error:\
    * Variable not in scope: main\
    * Perhaps you meant `min' (imported from Prelude)"
```

Código:

```
sumaComplejos :: (Int,Int) ->(Int,Int) -> (Int,Int)
sumaComplejos (x1,x2) (y1,y2) = (x1+y1,x2+y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Tienes que declarar la función:

```
suma :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

- Tienes que definir la función:

```
suma x y =  x + y
```

- Luego, como en muchos lenguajes Haskell comienza la compilación en `main`:

```
main = do 
   putStrLn "La suma de los numeros complejos es: "  
   print(suma 2 5)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El porqué del error es la falta de `main` en tu código.